# How to duplicate items in a list?

Tags: python, class, duplicates, blackjack

Just started learning Python and as a first project, I am trying to create a blackjack game where a shoe has more than 1 deck of cards (the number of deck is determined by user input, where:

```
suits = ["Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades"]
values = ["A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"]


class Card():
    def __init__ (self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit)

class Deck():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]
        for suit in suits:
            for value in values:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,value))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()

class Shoes():
    def __init__(self):
        self.decknum = int(input("Enter the number of deck used in a shoes: "))
        self.shoes = {}
        for i in range(1, self.decknum+1):
            self.shoes[str(i)] = [Deck()]
        print(self.shoes)
```

Ideally I would like to have a list with 6 deck of cards and make it into a shoes class but I don't know how to duplicate items in my deck list and convert it into a class.

ex: `shoe = ['A spades', 'A spades', 'A spades', 'A spades', 'A spades', 'A spades', '2 spades', ... 'K hearts']`

then class `Shoes()`:

Comment: Why don't you populate your list with it's own values but at the end. Using a for loop, just store the current length of your list, iterate over it, take the value, append it.

Comment: I think it depends a little on how you wanna use this `shoe` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I took the `input` outside of the `__init__` method. I also made suits and values parameters to `Deck` and `Shoes` with default values. This allows to to have special decks with only red cards for example by calling `Deck(suits=["Hearts", "Diamonds"])`.

The approach followed for `Shoes` is excactly the same you used for `Deck`.

```
DEFAULT_SUITS = ("Clubs","Hearts","Diamonds","Spades")
DEFAULT_VALUES = ("A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K")


class Card():
    def __init__ (self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit)

class Deck():
    def __init__(self, suits=DEFAULT_SUITS, values=DEFAULT_VALUES):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for value in values:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,value))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()

class Shoes():
    def __init__(self, decks, suits=DEFAULT_SUITS, values=DEFAULT_VALUES):
        self.cards = []
        for deck in range(decks):
            for suit in suits:
                for value in values:
                    self.cards.append(Card(suit,value))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()


shoe = Shoes(int(input("Enter the number of deck used in a shoes: ")))
shoe.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was looking at the code and had a question regarding the input part. Is it the number that I am inputting getting used in range(decks)?

Comment: @icswannabe Exactly. You input the number of decks (e.g. 6), which is passed as a parameter to Shoes. `range(6)` is more or less equivalent to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` so it makes 6 iterations in that loop, each of one will create a full deck.

Comment: gotcha, didnt know you can loop like that! learned something new thank you so much!

Comment: @icswannabe `for i in range(N):` is the pythonic way of doing `for i:=0; i<N; i++ {`. Notice that N is not included. `range` can also be provided additional arguments, check for its syntax, but it also allows to provide the start and the step.

Answer (score 0):

```
suits = ["Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"]
values = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]


class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    def show(self):
        print(self.value, self.suit)


class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for value in values:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, value))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            card.show()


class Shoes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.decknum = int(input("Enter the number of deck used in a shoes: "))
        self.shoes = []
        for i in range(1, self.decknum + 1):
            self.shoes += Deck().cards

        self.shoes.sort(key=lambda x: x.value)
        for card in self.shoes:
            card.show()

s = Shoes()
```